# how to resolve a Service Problems on icinga2?

Tags: icinga2

I have this error on my `icinga` server, can you help me please to resolve it?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Its mostly means that the user in which icinga is running as does not have enough privileges to access the mount

Answer (score 0):

You can use sudo in your command by swapping `PluginDir` in the command  like this:

```
object CheckCommand "ap_status" {
    import "plugin-check-command"
    command = [
        "/usr/bin/sudo",
        "/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_ap_status.pl"
    ]
    arguments += {
        "-C" = "$snmp_community$"
        "-H" = "$address$"
        "-O" = "$ap_status_ip_oid$"
        "-c" = "$ap_status_crit$"
        "-o" = "$ap_status_name_oid$"
        "-w" = "$ap_status_warn$"
    }
}
```

Or in [director](https://github.com/Icinga/icingaweb2-module-director) like:

[image: https://imgur.com/KWAAYry]